# Kentico Pager.PageCount 0 when page param exceeds page count

Tags: asp.net, kentico, ascx

Is there a way to get the Pager.PageCount value when the page param exceeds the max number of pages available?

In the below code totalPages = 3 so long as the page param is between 1 and 3.

However, if the page param is > 3, the value for totalPages = 0. I want to get the value for totalPages so I can redirect the client to the last page.

```
private void InitRepeater()
{
    RepItems.ClassNames = ClassNames;
    RepItems.MaxRelativeLevel = MaxRelativeLevel;
    RepItems.OrderBy = OrderBy;
    RepItems.SelectTopN = SelectTopN;
    RepItems.Path = Path;
    RepItems.FilterOutDuplicates = true;
    RepItems.SelectOnlyPublished = true;
    RepItems.SelectedColumns = GetSelectedColumns();
    SetCategories();

    Pager.PageSize = PagingPageSize;
    Pager.DisplayFirstLastAutomatically = true;
    Pager.DisplayPreviousNextAutomatically = true;
    Pager.HidePagerForSinglePage = true;
    Pager.GroupSize = 3;
    Pager.PageControl = RepItems.ID;
    Pager.UseQueryParameterForFirstPage = true;
    DataBind();

    var currentPage = Pager.CurrentPage;
    var totalPages = Pager.PageCount; 
    WebpartExtensions.ValidatePageParam((ulong)currentPage, (ulong)totalPages);
    WebpartExtensions.UpdateSEOBotLinks(Page, currentPage, totalPages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround

```
var currentPage = Pager.CurrentPage;
var totalPages = Pager.PageCount;
if(totalPages <= 0)
{
    //page param greater than amount of pages, reset to page 1 to get total pages
    Pager.CurrentPage = 1;
    RepItems.ReloadData(true);
    totalPages = Pager.PageCount;
    Pager.CurrentPage = totalPages;
    RepItems.ReloadData(true);
}
WebpartExtensions.ValidatePageParam((ulong)currentPage, (ulong)totalPages);
WebpartExtensions.UpdateSEOBotLinks(Page, currentPage, totalPages);
```